# How to disable auto shutdown due to overheating on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

my laptop tends to shut down automatically like every 25 minutes..
This is so frustrating. please help..
I am using ubuntu 14.04 server

Comment: You may be well served by checking into why you are having thermal issues - I use tlp on my laptop to help control heat, and I know there are other solutions.

Comment: That's a bad idea, it shuts down for a reason. As Charles said, you need to solve the problem not hide the symptoms.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should not do this because it prevents damaging your notebook. Better repair it (clean dust and replace thermointerface) and it will be as new.
Second, you can't disable it. It is ACPI function and works outside OS. Unless there is some switch in your BIOS settings, you can't disable it. You can disable ACPI altogether, but this means no screensaver, no shutdown on lid closing and power consumption as if you are playing Crysis all the time.

Comment: What I don't understand is why can't it just hibernate on overheating instead of shutting down?  It isn't anymore risky, Ubuntu takes minutes to shutdown anyway, all while being overheated...

Comment: Also, my laptop is crappy and almost always runs between 70 and 80 C, but max temp is 100C, *but* Ubuntu shuts down at 84C, usually it is only there for a microsecond before the fan catches up, it never stays there, but then it is too late and I just lost all my work!